# how to forward engineer database diagram from visio 2003 file?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visio

I came across some vb macros that export it to a mdb ( ms access ) file. But does not work very well when copying forward constraints , etc.

I want generate schema from the database diagram for **sql server 2005** database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For Visio 2007, as that's what I have to hand, although I remember that 2003 was very similar)

From the Database menu, select "Options" > "Drivers...", and change the default driver to suit.

Comment: i thought this only work for reverse engineering database schema ?

Comment: I tried it on my box before posting, and it certainly changes the available datatypes to suit nvarchar(max), etc. I strongly suspect that it wouldn't change existing values though

Answer (score 0):

Forward Engineering is supported only in "Enterprise Architect" versions of Visio